# In Railo, how do I delete a cookie?

Tags: session, cookies, coldfusion, railo

I am using Railo - CFML and it seems that it is not using application.cfc/.cfm because I have deleted those from the folder and it worked just the same. With that being said.

I am trying to force cookies to be deleted when I someone logs out of my application. Some how the information is being restored after I have forced the information in the cookie to be changed.

I have physically deleted the cookie and it forces a CFID update. However, that's the only time that I have been able to get a CFID change. I have looked more into the cookie and using my web developer toolkit, the cookie is set to expire in 2045.

I have searched on here for hours looking for methods to work and I can tell you so far they work on other projects that I have worked on but for some reason I cannot get it to work on this current project. Just a heads up, I am the 15th programmer on this site.

Here is some of the code that I am working with:

```
<cfcookie
name="CFID"
value="Dead"
expires="NOW"> 
<cfcookie
name="cfid"
value="Dead"
expires="NOW">

<cfset structClear( session ) />

<cfset delete_cookie=StructDelete(cookie,"CFID")>

<cfcookie name="CFID" value="0" expires="Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT">
<cfoutput>Cookie Deleted: #delete_cookie#<br /></cfoutput>

 <cfset delete_cookie=StructDelete(cookie,"cfid")>
<cfcookie name="cfid" value="0"expires="Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT">

<cfset delete_cookie_ga=StructDelete(cookie,"_ga")>
<cfcookie name="_ga" value="0"expires="Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT">
<!--- Redirect back to index page. --->
<!----<cflocation
url="/"
addtoken="false"
/>--->
<cfdump var=#cookie#>
```

Here is what I am getting:
Before I use that code.
Scope
_ga      string GA###########
cfid     string (random letters & numbers)
cftoken  string 50

After I use that code I get:
Scope
_ga      string 0
cfid     string 0
cftoken  string 50

This is me trying 2 different ways to get the job done.

However, after I run this and look at my cookies for my site, I still see the CFID with an expiration of 2045.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some code you've tried.  You may also want to check out http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/ to get an idea of what Application.cfc does and how it's used.

Comment: I have read that and it's a great resource.

Comment: @Abram I have added some code for you to see.

Comment: It is a great resource, and you'll probably want to read it again as it doesn't seem you understand what the Application.cfc is doing. Curious, why are you trying to delete the cfid and cftoken cookies? Why are you using cookies instead of the session scope?

Comment: I understand the importance of Application.cfc. However, Application.cfc is not being used for this site. Why, I do not know. I am coming in on a website that has had about 15 different programmers through the years and I am trying to clean it up and make it more secured. I have been trying to convert from cookies to session scopes and I was hoping someone may suggest something that is a switch in railo that I over looked.

Comment: The reason why I want to delete or update the cookies is because the programmer before me allowed these id's to be passed through the URL and people have shared these urls with the information and if you click on these tokens, you are immediately logged into the site with their account. That's why I am trying to delete these. For security issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for manipulating the cookie values on Railo. It appears Railo is performing session management tasks after the code has completed, and is setting the cfid cookies back.

Even if you could change the cfid cookie value, the existing session would still exist. Those that can view the session with the cfid in a url would still be able to use the corresponding session until it naturally times out. To invalidate a session in Railo 4 or higher you can use the `SessionInvalidate()` [function](http://www.railodocs.org/function/sessioninvalidate). This function will update the clients cfid, and force the current session to expire.

Without knowing more about your application, I’m unsure if invalidating the session will resolve the security issues you have been working on.

Comment: PERFECT! That works beautifully! Thank you so much for that. With that and the shorter session end timer. This will work wonderfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After further research I have found that my Railo Server admin had the sessions to time out after 90 days. This has been changed and the sessions expire after 20 mins. So if you use railo make sure that you update web admin and not just server admin. Lesson learned. Thanks everyone. Also a HUGE thank you to [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm) for helping with this problem!